# How to access global variables in groovy

Tags: groovy, constants, global-variables

I have a really simple groovy script-

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field final static String VARIABLE = 'Variable'

static void main(String[] args) {
    println VARIABLE
}
```

But the output is empty, how can I make a global, static constant in groovy and use it in static methods?

Comment: Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

to use a global static constant i would use this syntax - maybe not perfect but always working:

```
class Const{
  final static String VARIABLE='value'
}

println "VARIABLE=${Const.VARIABLE}"
```

---

avoid using `static void main()` in groovy scripts - this way you could conflict with groovy script-to-class transformation

https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_public_static_void_main_vs_script